# How to change Mage::log() timestamp of magento 1.8?

Tags: php, magento, datetime, logging

I want to change the logging time stamp of Magento into different timezone, anybody has any idea how to do it.

Comment: If you have multi store setup you can go to 
System > Configuration > General > Locale Options > Timezone and change Timezone. More you can print to know the current time
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", Mage::getModel('core/date')->timestamp(time()));exit;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't found any other way to do that at last I modified Mage.php and modify log function and add/replace the below code to get my selected time zone in log file.

```
$storeTimeZone = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", Mage::getModel('core/date')->timestamp(time()));
$loggers[$file]->log($storeTimeZone.' '.$message, $level);
```

I have add it on line# 841 of Mage.php, if any of you want to do the same than you can try this dirty trick.

Comment: i have added answer

Answer (score 0):

Magento internally sets all cron dates to occur in GMT, it actually overrides the server php time zone settings so that all log events and all cron time schedules are triggered in the GMT timezone - you can see this in Mage.php on line 767. All php time functions called within Magento will be in GMT as a result.

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
```

Magento then adds back your timezone offset based on your locale settings when it shows you times in the admin panel.

It does this so you can run multiple stores in different timezones based on your locale choice.

Check your timestamp

```
$storetimestamp = Mage::getModel('core/date')->timestamp(time());
$storetime = date("H:i:s",$storetimestamp)
```

Comment: I don't see GMT timezone on line 527 of Mage.php

Comment: date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

Comment: It is at line no:767 in magento 1.7

Comment: @Simshaddyyy But you didnt mention how can we change the timestamp that is displaying at log files

Comment: Did u try by modifying the server time? I heard that it will collect that timestamp from the server.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.. I am from INDIA. So in `app/mage.php` at the same `line no:767`, I modified as `date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta');`, then it started displaying my time as time stamp in log files. So you too place your own time zone.

Comment: Are you sure that it will not effect the other parts as well?

Comment: It will effect.. I tested with making an order. Previously when I made an order, it will be created by default timestamp in orders at admin panel. But this is not correct timestamp. If you change as above, now you can see the current timestamp at orders also.

Answer (score 0):

Copy File `lib/Zend/Log.php` TO `app/code/local/Zend/Log.php`

and modify function `_packEvent` => `timestamp` TO `$storeTimeZone = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", Mage::getModel('core/date')->timestamp(time()));`